# Pandas Replace changes values not only in the dataframe it is applied to

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],['a',1]])
df1 = df1.replace(1, np.nan)
```

So, df1 takes [this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usGKP.png).

After this, I want to replace some values in df2:

```
df2 = df1
df2[1] = df2[1].replace(np.nan, 0)
df1
```

Now, surprisingly, df1 changes: its bottom right value [is replaced as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfqQt.png).

Could you please briefly explain why df1 changes in this case? Is there any way to apply the replacement I want to df2 without changing df1?

Comment: Assignment NEVER copies data. You just gave a second name to `df1`. `df2 = df1.copy()`.

Comment: watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns), it should be mandatory :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, python goes for shallow copy of variables i.e. any changes made to any variable will be reflected to the object that was assigned as well hence both df1 & df2 changes in your case. You can use deepcopy() to avoid this

```
import copy
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],['a',1]])
df1 = df1.replace(1, np.nan)

df2 = copy.deepcopy(df1)
df2[1] = df2[1].replace(np.nan, 0)
```

changes will reflect only in df2 but not in df1